# Проблема с созданием экземпляра класса

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Только начинаю изучать PHP и ООП в целом. Проблема следующая: при попытке создать экземпляры player 1 и player 2 немного разными способами player 2 не создаётся. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка. Код прикладываю. Заранее спасибо.

```
<?php

class Player {

    private $name;
    private $city;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setCity($city) {
        $this->city = $city;
    }

}


$player1 = new Player('Max');
$player1->setCity("Minsk");
var_dump ($player1);
echo'<br>';
$player2 = (new Player("Dmitry"))->setCity("Brest");
var_dump($player2);
```

что вижу при выводе:

```
object(Player)[1]
  private 'name' => string 'Max' (length=3)
  private 'city' => string 'Minsk' (length=5)

F:\WAMP\www\frintoProject\player.php:24:null
```

Comment: В первом варианте вы переменной присваиваете экземпляр класса, а во втором то, что по идее должен возвращать метод `setCity`, хотя он ничего у вас не возвращает. Если и во втором случае нужен объект, например для "Fluid Interface", то возвращайте `$this` в методе `setCity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если для второго случая нужен в качестве результата этот самый объект (например для "Fluid Interface"), то необходимо вернуть `$this` в методе `setCity`

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема решена.